# Long value in object field not sent though REST

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object with a `Value` field. This field contains a very long string (base64). When using `console.log`, the field seems to contain the string, however, when just printing out this one field, I just get an empty string:
[image]

I'm trying to send this object through a REST service, but it just sends the empty string instead of the correct value.

What is going on here? I've used these kind of strings before and it worked fine, but now it looks like I'm missing something important.

To make it clear, this gets the above output:

```
console.log(myObject);
```

This prints an empty string:

```
console.log(myObject.Value);
```

EDIT:
This is how the `Value` is assigned:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < vm.data.profileSettings.length; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            var setting = vm.data.settings.filter(function(setting) { return setting.Id == vm.data.profileSettings[i].Id });

            if (setting[0].Type == 2 && vm.data.profileSettings[i].copiedValue && typeof(vm.data.profileSettings[i].copiedValue) == 'object') {
                Upload.base64DataUrl(vm.data.profileSettings[i].copiedValue)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        var splitted =  response.split(",");

                        vm.data.profileSettings[i].Value = splitted[1];
                    });

            }
        })(i);
    }

    profileDataService.saveProfileSettings(vm.data.selectedProfile.Id, vm.data.profileSettings)
    .then(function(response) {
        vm.success = true;
    });
```

Comment: console is not a snapshot when you log objects unless you stringify them.  Sounds like value is added after you log the whole object. Show us the code

Comment: That what I was supecting already. However, I thought the way I wrote the code would make sure the API call (saveprofileSettings) would not be executed before the loop ends.

I've added the code, thanks

Comment: But `Upload` is asynchronous

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't putting the whole loop in a new function block solve that issue? If not, what can I do to assure the call is only made when the async Upload calls are completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Upload()` is asynchronous so you need all the `Upload` to complete before you send your final data since that data is dependent on responses from uploads.

You can create array of upload promises and use `$q.all()` to run code when all of those promises have resolved

---

Create empty array before the loop and push each upload promise into that array

```
var uploadPromises = []
```

Then change

```
Upload.base64DataUrl(vm.data.profileSettings[i].copiedValue)
                .then(function(response) {
                   // do stuff with response
                });
```

To

```
var req =  Upload.base64DataUrl(vm.data.profileSettings[i].copiedValue)
                .then(function(response) {
                   // do stuff with response
                });
 uploadPromises.push(req);
```

Now wrap your final request

```
$q.all(uploadPromises ).then(function(){    
    profileDataService.saveProfileSettings(...)
}).catch(function(err){
   // do something when any upload promise is rejected
});
```

Note you will need to determine strategy if any upload promise gets rejected. You can use a catch on upload promises themselves to also resolve that promise if that's what you want to do so final request will always be made

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution seems to work perfectly! Also thanks for the clear explanation =)

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing that your long String is a file encoded to base64.
Then you can use btoa() and atob() to convert to and from base64 encoding.

You can have a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/247261/2886514

Comment: his problem is something different than your answer i guess

Comment: doesn't explain undefined value